# How to fetch data by id Swift

Tags: swift

So I'm saving data in my database by id to be retrieved by id using `http://localhost:8000/albums/whateverId` so that is what I'm trying to do in my Swift app, retrieve data by id, by first retrieving all the ids then trying to implement those ids in my url and fetch my data by id.

**Fetch all the data (retrieving ids)**

```
class Webservice {
    func getAllPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Variables**

```
struct Post: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let path: String
    let description: String
}
```

**Set the variables to the data from `completion(posts)` in `class Webservice`**

```
final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }

    @Published var posts = [Post]()


    private func fetchPosts() {
        Webservice().getAllPosts {
            self.posts = $0
        }
    }

}
```

---

**And Here's How I'm Trying To Get The Data By Id By Using The id From The Data I Just Fetched**

**Here's how I would fetch the data using the url with a certain id**

```
class SecondWebService: Identifiable {
    var id:String = ""

    init(id: String?) {
        self.id = id!
        }

    func getAllPostsById(completion: @escaping ([PostById]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums/\(id)")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([PostById].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Variables**

```
struct PostById: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let path: String
}
```

**Iterate through my data from PostListViewModel() from the first section and implement id into my `class SecondWebService` using the url to get data by id**

```
final class PostListViewByIdModel: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()

    init() {
       fetchPostsById()
     }

    @Published var postsById = [PostById]()

    private func fetchPostsById() {
        for post in model.posts {
          SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById {
            self.postsById = $0
             print("ALL THAT \($0)")

        }
    }


 }

}
```

I feel like this code should work but it's not printing anything.

Comment: Did you step through the code to see what's happening? Are you sure that model has posts?

Comment: It does when I print it in the function fetchPosts in the first section of code. The `"ALL THAT"` isn't even getting printed

Comment: Hmmm when I try to print posts in that function where I call `SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById` nothing is printed so maybe model doesn't have posts yet. How can I make sure that it does before I do `for post in model.posts {
          SecondWebService(id: post.id).getAllPostsById {
            self.postsById = $0
             print("ALL THAT \($0)")

        }
    }
`

Comment: Not sure if related, but shouldn't it be `JSONDecoder().decode(PostById.self, from: data!)` ?